# Есть ли способ быстро получать ссылку в текущей вкладке в Chrome?

Tags: c#, winapi

На просторах SO полно вот такого [кода](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp), но работает он просто ужасно медленно, по 3-5 секунд... Есть ли способ быстро получить url?